# Kotlin how apply different functions by predictor

Tags: kotlin

I need to apply 2 different functions to my list in Kotlin based on external map, saving initial order of the list.

```
class Example(){

    val mapper = mapOf<String, Int>(
        "abc" to 1,
        "de" to 0,
        "fedd" to 1,
        "q" to 1
    )

    fun function1(x:String)=x.length*2
    fun function0(x:String)=x.length*3

    fun function(lst: List<String>){
        TODO("Need to apply function1 for all values in dictionary, where corresponding value in mapper is 1" +
            "And apply function 0 for all values where corresponding value in mapper is 0")
    }
}
```

So, for list `["q", "fedd", "de"]` method `Example.function()` should return `[2, 8, 6]`

2 -> `q` value in mapper is 1, applying function1, multiplying by 2, get 1*2=2

8 -> `fedd` in mapper is 1, applying function1, multiplying by 2, get 4*2=8

6 -> `de` in mapper is 0, applying function0, multiplying by 3, get 2*3=6

What is the easiest way to realise this logic?

Comment: For each element in the list you need to get the corresponding value in the map. Then, if the result is 1 apply function1. If it's 0 apply function0. You also need to specify what to do when the value is not in the map. Have you tried something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use map on the list to achieve this. follow below:

```
val mapper = mapOf<String, Int>(
    "abc" to 1,
    "de" to 0,
    "fedd" to 1,
    "q" to 1
)

fun function1(x: String) = x.length * 2
fun function0(x: String) = x.length * 3

fun function(lst: List<String>) {
   val newList =  lst.map {
        when (mapper[it]) {
            0 -> function0(it)
            1 -> function1(it)
            else -> error("Key doesn't exist in map, throw or return value as is.")
        }
    }
}
```